# Detect orientation in reverse landscape and portrait mode

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I want to detect reverse landscape and portrait orientation. Configuration does not support  `ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE` or `ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT`.

I have also tried `Activityinfo.ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT` but it's also not working.help me.

```
if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

    Log.e("On Config Change","LANDSCAPE");
}else{

    Log.e("On Config Change","PORTRAIT");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if your device has a magnetometer you can differentiate between landscape and reverse landscape by calculating the rotational attitude of the device (azimuth, pitch, and roll) using the `SensorManager` methods `getRotationMatrix()` and `getOrientation()`.  If the roll is positive, you're in reverse landscape (landscape right), and if the roll is negative you're in landscape (landscape left).

Similarly, you can use the pitch to differentiate between portrait and reverse portrait.  If the pitch is positive, you're in reverse portrait, and if the pitch is negative you're in portrait.

If your device doesn't have a magnetometer, you can use the x-axis and y-axis values of the accelerometer to differentiate between landscape and reverse landscape.  A negative x-axis value indicates reverse landscape (landscape right), and a positive value indicates landscape.  Similarly, a negative y-axis value indicates reverse portrait, and a positive y-axis value indicates portrait.